# cron job not running in docker fastapi docker app

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, fastapi

I'm working on an app for my homelab, where I have an Intel NUC I'm using for some web scraping tasks.  The NUC is accessible to my home network via `192.xxx.x.xx`.

On the NUC I've set up `nginx` to proxy incoming http request to a `docker` container.  In that container I've got a basic `fastapi` app to handle the request.

### app.main.py

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
cron_path = Path(os.getcwd(), "app", "cron.log")

@app.get("/cron")
def cron():
    with cron_path.open("rt") as cron:
        return {"cron_state": cron.read().split("\n")}
```

### app.cronjob.py

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

cron_path = Path(os.getcwd(), "app", "cron.log")

def append_time():
    with cron_path.open("rt") as filein:
        text = filein.read()
        text += f"\n{datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}"
        
    with cron_path.open("wt") as fileout:
        fileout.write(text)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    append_time()
```

### cron-job

```bash
* * * * * python3 /code/app/cronjob.py
# An empty line is required at the end of this file for a valid cron file.
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

# 
WORKDIR /code

COPY ./cron-job /etc/cron.d/cron-job
COPY ./app /code/app
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron-job
#Install Cron
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cron
# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cron-job

# 
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

# 
EXPOSE 8080

CMD crontab ; uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```

I can access the the app without issues, but I can't seem to get the cron job to run while fastapi is running.  Is what I'm attemping to do something better suited for pure python solution like `from fastapi_utils.tasks import repeat_every` or is there something I'm missing.

Comment: You are not running a cron daemon in your container. There is nothing to execute your cron job (you probably don't *want* to run a cron daemon in your container: you would typically run this in a second container, using volumes as necessary for shared state).

Comment: So I’m going to ask another related question that deviates from the original task. I have a separate work project that executes tasks on time & data events. The data events are likely to come from a Kafka stream and time events TBD. The events will trigger api calls.  I guess my question is why shouldn’t I use the python built in scheduling rather than the os from lime jobs.

Comment: I think if you can drive your scheduling requirements with Python that's a fine solution.